# sample for gcm server for application server which deployed on google app engine in java

Tags: google-app-engine, xmpp, smack

I am developing a server which runs on google app engine, and wants to develop push notifications which can notify my android device.

Tried using smack client , but it is not working on GAE...

IF any one has good sample for this , can you please share?

Answer (score 0):

You cant set up a Smack server on GAE. Try using [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to deliver push notifications.

Comment: Smack seems to be incompatible with Google App Engine, because it tries to open a new thread on `XMPPTCPConnection.connect()`. Google App Engine does not allow this, resulting in a crash on launch.